# How to print word documents with comments using OpenOffice?

Tags: printing, microsoft-word, openoffice, openoffice-writer

I received a word document that contains comments which are shown to the right of the page. When I print the document the comments are not printed, whereas the changes in the text are.

How can I also print the the comments?

I tried to create a PDF first and included the comments, but in the text only a symbol is shown. I have to click on the symbol first to see the comment. The comments are not included on the printed version of those PDF documents.

So, is it possible to include the comments when printing the document? (I saw that it is possible in Microsoft word).

I'm using OpenOffice 3.2.0, OOO320m12 (Build: 9483) on MacOSX Leopard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't exactly duplicate the way MS Word prints the comments (on the right side) but try this:

- Open `Tools`->`Options`->`OpenOffice.org Writer`->`Print`
- Set the Comments option to `End of document` or `End of page`

Comment: OK, this is something the developers still have to work on. I was quite glad that they managed to include the comments on the right side. But printig the comments is not very good solved. At least for my document the line is not correctly shown in the printout (it is always 65535), although it is correctly displayed in the document. It would be also nice to be asked what to print out, when trying to print a document with comments.